# Adjusting JPanels to correct size

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, preferredsize

I have my code in this format, but the jpanels are not listening the size i set. All the three panels are in the same size when i run the code. Is there any way to adjust them?

```
JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel(mainPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
JPanel tablepanel1 = new JPanel();
tablepanel1.setSize(900,400);
JPanel selectionpanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
selectionpanel.setSize(900,100);
JPanel tablepanel2 = new JPanel();
tablepanel2.setSize(900,400);

mainpanel.add(tablepanel1);
mainpanel.add(selectionpanel);
mainpanel.add(tablepanel2);

frame.add(mainpanel);
frame.setSize(900,900);
```

Comment: If you want absolute positioning in Swing, I'd say you can't use a layout manager for `mainPanel`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: Use `setPreferredSize` instead of `setSize`.  Also, `BorderLayout` doesn't have a member called `Y_AXIS` -- perhaps you mean `BoxLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to use `BoxLayout` for `mainpanel`?:

```
JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();
mainpanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainpanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

This layout manager only listens to *preferred sizes* rather than the component size. The best way is to override `getPreferredSize`:

```
JPanel selectionpanel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(900, 400);
    }
};
```

Also better to use `JFrame#pack` rather than setting dimensions for the frame.

Comment: sorry, yes it is boxLayout, but i tried using the method that you suggested, but no change. i need to set size to jframe, because at first the frame will be empty with menubar and once the action is selected the panels will be added and frame doesnt increase its size.

Comment: I tested this & it works. Did you override `getPreferredSize` for the 3 panels: `tablepanel1`, `tablepanel2` & `selectionpanel`?